# Confirm HLS server is working only with Windows PC

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, windows

I'm going to set up HTTP Live Streaming server.
In development environment, only Windows PC is available for the server's client due to network restriction and other regulations.

How can I confirm that

- server is publishing HLS movie and
- real-time movie's delay by viewing it

only with Windows software?

[This page](http://www.jwplayer.com/html5/hls/) shows that browser available on Windows does not support HLS.
I'm prefer solution with free software, so [JW Player](http://www.jwplayer.com/) may not be a best solution.

I'm not sure that I can check delay on-the-fly with [hls-client](https://github.com/globocom/hlsclient) or ffmpeg.

Comment: Thank you. I gave it a try with http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/bipbop/bipbop.m3u8 and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VLC, ffmpeg, and XBMC support playing HLS on Windows. A longer list can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming#Clients